# XAML Usercontrol Image stretch to available size

Tags: image, xaml, user-controls, grid

I have an image as a drawing brush in xaml. The only property set is Stretch, which is set to Uniform.

The image is then set to the background of a usercontrol which has no properties set with regards to size.

The usercontrol is then used within a a grid, and set to span 2 rows like so:

```
    <common:Logo 
         Height="130"
         Width="500"
         Grid.Column="0" 
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.RowSpan="2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        />
```

The problem is that there is loads of white space on top and below the image, which is also quite small.

The image started as a vector graphic and has no space above or below. 
When I view the usercontrol with sizes set, it fits perfectly with no white space.

I am hoping this is not a problem with the grid reporting an incorrect size.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio was not refreshing any of the changes, running the code and reviewing what was produced fixed the whole problem!